# How do I connect to MongoDB with SSL in Scala?

Tags: mongodb, scala, ssl

I'm trying to set up an ssl connection to a mongodb instance I have running in a container on my machine and keep running into,

```
nioEventLoopGroup-2-4, fatal error: 46: General SSLEngine problem
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I created a self signed .pem for mongo with,

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout mongo.key -out mongo.crt -days 365 -nodes
cat mongo.key mongo.cert > mongo.pem
```

Moved those into a folder, mounted it as a bind volume in my container and added

```
--sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/boundfolder/mongo.pem
```

to the mongo startup. I can connect to this with the mongo client.

I am setting up my mongo client in scala like so,

```
val hostConf = ClusterSettings.builder().hosts(List(new ServerAddress(hostName)).asJava).build()
val clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
    .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactoryFactory())
    .clusterSettings(hostConf)
val withTLS = clientSettings.sslSettings(
    SslSettings.builder()
        .enabled(true)
        .invalidHostNameAllowed(true)
        .build())
MongoClient(withTLS.build())
```

Lastly, I created a keystore with,

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file mongo.crt -keystore mongo.keystore
```

and am starting the application with the following parameters,

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/mongo.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.debug=SSL
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is either what, or how, I'm adding the self signed cert to the keystore. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Does the error happen if you use a connection string? something like this: `MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost/?ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true&streamType=netty")`

Comment: Wish I was aware of the streamType=netty option earlier, I would have tried it. I just solved the issue with a combination of the following 2 pages:
https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.13/gtpd5/tmdbssljava.html